# Construction call to super fails for Groovy object inheriting 3rd-Party Java object

Tags: gradle, groovy, compiler-errors

### The Situation

I have a Groovy subclass of a Java class. The Java class is from a dependency, not my own local package:

```
// A basic idea of the Java class' construction
public class JavaArea<PS, S> {

    public JavaArea(PS initialStyle, BiConsumer, S otheStyle, Biconsumer) {
        // constructs class...
    }

}

class GroovyArea extends JavaArea<Collection<String>, Collection<String>> {

    GroovyArea(Object unrelated arguments) {
        super(Collections.emptyList(), defaultBiConsumer, otherStyle, defaultBiConsumer)
        // do some other stuff to GroovyArea's fields
    }

}
```

For some reason, the compilation of the class fails with:`Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor` despite the constructor call being the first statement...

```
Exception executing 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler@7a1c5b43 
in compiler daemon: 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: 
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details..

    super(Collections.emptyList(), otherParams)
          ^
```

### The Gradle Build files

I have the following build file for the root project:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'groovy'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.6'

        testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4"
        testRuntime "cglib:cglib-nodep:3.2.3"
        testRuntime "org.objenesis:objenesis:2.4"
    }
}
```

... and the following build file for the actual module containing the error:

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovyfx:groovyfx:0.4.0'

    compile project(':diagrammer')

    compile group: 'org.reactfx', name: 'reactfx', version: '2.0-M5'
    compile group: 'org.fxmisc.wellbehaved', name: 'wellbehavedfx', version: '0.3'
    compile (group: 'org.fxmisc.richtext', name: 'richtextfx', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude group:'org.reactfx', module: 'reactfx'
    }

}
```

### My Question

What's causing the problem and how do I fix it? Is this a bug with Groovy? Or an issue with my build environment?

IDE: IntelliJ 2016.1.3 

I don't think it's the IDE because it performs syntax highlighting correctly and provides the correct documentation when I hover over the 'super' keyword

Gradle: Gradle 2.12

Groovy: Groovy 2.4.6

### What I have tried

I've tried changing the versions of Gradle (via `sdkman`) and then Groovy (via build file). None of these have fixed the problem:

- Gradle: `2.12`, `2.14`

  - using Groovy: `2.4.5`, `2.4.6`, `2.4.7`

### Updates

- Creating a new Gradle project in IntelliJ that only has the necessary components to rebuild the GroovyArea class will fail with the same exception when I run `gradle build`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a bug in Groovy. Filed as [GROOVY-7868](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7868)